# Gmail Add-in Is there any way to update the opened reply draft GmailApp

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons, gsuite-addons

I'm developing a gmail add-on. I have created a feature to create a reply draft when user fill some text inputs and click on a button (There are some API calls to create email body by using these details).

> ```
> function composeReply(e){
>             var messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
>             var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
>             ......
>             var msg = {
>               htmlBody: result['email_content'],
>               subject: result['email_subject']
>             }
>     
>             var draft = message.createDraftReply('', msg);
>             return CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder().setGmailDraft(draft).build();
>
>     }
> ```

In the above function I want to check whether the message have already a reply draft then update that else create a new reply draft
Or Is there any way to delete the existing draft before creating a new one

Comment: So do you basically want to check if a draft for that thread of messages does already exists and if so to delete it?

Comment: Yes. that's also fine for me. My issue is, now for each click addon is creating a new draft.

Comment: So in your Add-On I assume you have a button that when pressed it creates a draft message am I right? Then why you dont want the button to create new drafts when clicked? Do you want to just create a single draft on click and then to stop the button from creating new drafts?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You can't do this using `GmailApp`, however you can use the Advanced Gmail Service to get a list of message drafts and check if the current message has the same thread ID as any of the drafts.*

#### Example:

Using the special `me` value for the user ID, you can make an Advanced Gmail service call to get a list of drafts:

```js
var response = Gmail.Users.Drafts.list("me");
```

As per the documentation on [Users.drafts: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/list), you will get an array of `users.drafts` resources in the response:

```
{
  "drafts": [
    users.drafts Resource
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "resultSizeEstimate": unsigned integer
}
```

You can then use [Users.messages: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) to get the thread ID from the current message:

```
var threadId = Gmail.Users.Messages.get("me", messageId).threadId
```

or by using `GmailApp`:

```
var threadId = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId).getThread().getId()
```

From here, you can loop through the drafts, checking if the thread IDs match, and if they do, then the draft already exists and you can delete it:

```js
try {
  response.drafts.forEach(function(draft) {
    if (draft.message.threadId == threadId) {
      throw draft.id;
    }
  });
}
catch (id) {
  Gmail.Users.Drafts.remove("me", id)
}  
// create new draft here
```

#### References:

- [Advanced Gmail Service | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail)
- [Users.drafts: delete | Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/delete)
- [Users.drafts: list | Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/list)
- [Users.messages: get | Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)